# Populate an array with unlimited index - Java

Tags: java, arrays, dimensions

Is there a way to populate an array with unlimited indexes in java? I just want the program to keep appending to the array without any capacity.

I declared like this:

`int arrInt[] = new int[]`

But it says that it is missing dimension. So how can I do it?

Comment: You can use ArrayList instead - it's unlimited and easier to handle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array in Java is static, ie. you have to declare its size while initializing. Hence the answer is 'no' and you are getting the correct message as you have not mentioned the dimension.

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge on this matter at hand! XD

Comment: Thanks for the kind acknowledgement

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

`ArrayList` serves that purpose (i.e. an array based list whose capacity increases over time automatically when adding elements to it).

Comment: Ok i think i will use this method as well.XD

Answer (score 1):

In java, arrays have a maximum number of elements equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5`. To get around this, try using a `LinkedList` which has an unimited number of elements. Since this is a list, you can modify the size whenever necessary in your code. Note that `ArrayList` also has a max number of elements of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so `LinkedList` is necessary if you truly need a list of unlimited size.

Resource: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Thank you. I will consider this! XD

Comment: Even for a LinkedList, functions like `add(index, element)` or `indexOf(element)` will start to break down if you somehow exceed max_int elements. (not sure how you would build such a huge list in practice, though)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to populate an array with unlimited indexes in java?

NO

> I just want the program to keep appending to the array without any
>   capacity.

Need to Use `ArrayList`

```
List<Object> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
arr.add(obj1);
arr.add(obj2);
arr.add(obj3); .. so on
```

> I declared like this - int arrInt[] = new int[]. But it says that it
>   is missing dimension.

Arrays will always complain to declare the size.